# Como serializar um objeto Hash da Hashlib para envio por Sockets?

Tags: python, socket, hash

Como é possível serializar um objeto do tipo `_hashlib.HASH` , para que o mesmo seja adequado para o envio via **sockets** (`sendall()` e `send()`) ?

Com o pickle é feito:

```
hashed_Message = hashlib.sha256(message.encode('utf-8'))
    
serializedHashed_Message = pickle.dumps(hashed_Message)
    
conn.sendall(serializedHashed_Message)
```

Mas ao se fazer isso acontece a seguinte exception:

> TypeError: can't pickle _hashlib.HASH objects

E ao se tentar enviar o objeto diretamente a função de envio requer bytes. Como lidar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [hash.digest()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.digest) para obter os bytes da hash e passar ao `conn.sendall`, sem precisar do `pickle`.

```
hashed_Message = hashlib.sha256(message.encode('utf-8'))
    
serializedHashed_Message = hashed_Message.digest()
    
conn.sendall(serializedHashed_Message)
```

Comment: Agradecido, era uma das formas que eu estava pensando em fazer, mas queria da outra forma, devido ao fato de existir outros objetos que não são tão simplesmente serializados.

Comment: Se essa `hash` for uma propriedade de um objeto, você pode tentar usar o `__setstate__` e `__getstate__` do pickle para converter para bytes ao serializar o objeto.